# Drupal Custom Module - Menu Hook using Query String

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Currently I have a custom module with hook_menu for path 'search'. It's working just fine. However, it couldn't process the request when I access /search?q=something.

How do I do this? I'm using Drupal 6 btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet your problem is that q is what drupal internally uses to parse the path. So

```
/search?q=something
```

will be translated internally into

```
/something
```

which is an entirely different page than the one you defined in your hook_menu. If you instead did

```
/search?p=something
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change to http://site/search?s=something (fox example, q already used by drupal)...